# How to Construct a Maximum Likelihood Estimator for Parameter from a Beta Distribution?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, beta-distribution

I have a question from my Stats Homework that is worded as follows:

```
Based on a random sample size n from the Beta(a,2), construct the MLE of a
```

I really don't know how to go about solving this, as the beta function in the pmf of the beta distribution is throwing me off. I would appreciate any input and guidance.

Comment: Go as far as you can by ignoring the beta term.  Come back here when you reach a point where you *must* use it in a calculation in order to find the MLE of $a$: then you will have a more specific question to ask.